# How to access existing db file

Tags: ios, swift

I tried to access but getting an error "no such table found" by using this method

```
let path =  try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false).appendingPathComponent("NewFile.db")

let database = FMDatabase(path: path.path)
if !database.open() {
    print("Unable to open database")
    return
}

    if let rs = database.executeQuery(" SELECT * FROM myowntable", withArgumentsIn: []) {
      while rs.next() {
        //...

      }
    } else {
      print("executeQuery failed: \(database.lastErrorMessage())")
    }


    database.close()
```

Comment: How do you initially create the file in your Documents folder?

Comment: i didn't created any file i added external db named NewFIle.db file to xcode project folder and i want to access it I'm new to sqlite.

Comment: Files in your app bundle are read-only. If you never need to update the database file then simply change how you get the path to the file (use `Bundle`, not `FileManager`). If you need to write to the database, you need to copy the initial database from the bundle to the Documents folder if it doesn't yet exist there. Then the code you posted should work.

Comment: Thank you i'll use bundle and get back to u